# How to normalize a Lmer model?

Tags: r, normalization, lme4

lmer:

```
mixed.lmer6 <- lmer(Size ~ (Time+I(Time^2))*Country*STemperature +
   (1|Country:Locality)+ (1|Locality:Individual)+(1|Batch)+
   (1|Egg_masses), REML = FALSE, data = data_NoNA)
```

residuals:

```
plot_model(mixed.lmer6, type = "diag")
```

[image: non-normality]

Tried manual log,power, sqrt transformations in my formula but no improvement and I also can not find a suitable automatic transformation R function such as BoxCox (which does not work for LMER's)

Any help or tips would be appreciated

Comment: Looking at the QQ plot, it looks like you have more extreme values than would be expected by a normal distribution, and they happen on both tails. I would look into a GLMM that uses a student-t distribution and see if that is better

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

This might be better suited for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) ("what should I do?" is appropriate for CV; "how should I do it?" is best for Stack Overflow), but I'll take a crack.

- The Q-Q plot is generally the **last**/least important diagnostic you should look at (the order should be *approximately* (1) check for significant bias/missed patterns in the mean [fitted vs. residual, residual vs. covariates]; (2) check for outliers/influential points [leverage, Cook's distance]; (3) check for heteroscedasticity [scale-location plot]; (4) check distributional assumptions [Q-Q plot]).  The reason is that any of the "upstream" failures (e.g. missed patterns) will show up in the Q-Q plot as well; resolving them will often resolve the apparent non-Normality.
- If you can fix the distributional assumptions by fixing something else about the model (adding covariates/adding interactions/adding polynomial or spline terms/removing outliers), then do that.
- you could code your own brute-force Box-Cox, something like

```
fitted_model <- lmer(..., data = mydata)
bcfun <- function(lambda, resp = "y") {
   y <- mydata[[resp]]
   mydata$newy <- if (lambda==0) log(y) else (y^lambda -1)/lambda
   ## https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261380/how-do-i-get-the-box-cox-log-likelihood-using-the-jacobian
   log_jac <- sum((lambda-1)*log(y))
   newfit <- update(fitted_model, newy ~ ., data = mydata)
   return(-2*(c(logLik(newfit))+ log_jac))
}
lambdavec <- seq(-2, 2, by = 0.2)
boxcox <- vapply(lambdavec, bcfun, FUN.VALUE = numeric(1))
plot(lambdavec, boxcox - min(boxcox))
```

(lightly tested! but feel free to let me know if it doesn't work)

- if you do need to fit a mixed model with a heavy-tailed residual distribution (e.g. Student t), the options are fairly limited. The `brms` package can fit such models (but takes you down the Bayesian/MCMC rabbit hole), and the `heavy` package (currently archived on CRAN) will work, but doesn't appear to handle crossed random effects.